# Display day of the week, hours and minutes, and date

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to adapt this script so it can also display the day of the week and the date.

```
(function () {
    function checkTime(i) {
        return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date(),
            h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
            m = checkTime(today.getMinutes());
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m;
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
    }
    startTime();
})();
```

I though about adding a `getDay();` but I don't know how to add it in the function to be honest. Knowing that the day and date must update automaticaly on the page, that will stay open for days.. (It's a display that will almost always stay on.)

Any idea ?

Comment: Why don't you know how to add it? `var d = today.getDate()` `...innerHTML = d + ':' + h ...`?

Comment: have you read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)? as far as the webpage not refreshing, just use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to recalculate the current time as often as you want.

Comment: @KevinKloet `setInterval()` is evil; it's much better to use a recursive call to `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @putvande This is what I tried but I forgot to add the "today". Why it is necessary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the month and day names to array, and then use [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) and [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear):

```js
(function () {
    function checkTime(i) {
        return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    function startTime() {
     var months = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ],
         days = [ 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ]
    
        var today = new Date(),
            d = today.getDay(),
            f = today.getDate(),
            m = today.getMonth(),
            y = today.getFullYear(),
            
            h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
            i = checkTime(today.getMinutes());
        
        var val = days[d]+', '+f+' '+months[m]+' '+y+' - '+h+':'+i;
        
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = val;
        
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
    }
    
    startTime();
})();
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ben ! Can you tell me about the return ? What does it does exactly ?

Comment: Which return? Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: There is a function `checkTime(i){}` in which there is a return. I don't really understand what it does.

Comment: It looks like a no sneaky way to pad zeroes to me.

Comment: I assumed you'd written that code. It sanitises the parameter passed to it, and pads the number with `0` to the left if it's `< 10`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dayNames = ["DOM", "LUN", "MAR", "MER", "GIO", "VEN", "SAB"],

dayNames[date.getDay()]
```

to show a string with your day.

have a look here to see a personal working example
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kfh

Comment: day names are sunday,monday... sorry but im italian

Answer (score 0):

**Use Below Code and Check it.
HTML**

```
 <div id="time"></div>
  <div id="day"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function () {
    function checkTime(i) {
        return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    function startTime() {
    var today = new Date(),
    ndays = [ 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ]
    h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
    m = checkTime(today.getMinutes());
    s = checkTime(today.getSeconds());
    dn = today.getDay(),

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var d=ndays[dn];
    document.getElementById('day').innerHTML=d;
    t = setTimeout(function () {
    startTime()
        }, 500);
    }
    startTime();
})();
```